# How to change the slide of owl carousel on form submit success

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal, laravel-8, owl-carousel

I have a modal where I am loading the owl carousel, now each items of owl carousel have a form, such that when a user will submit the form it will first process the form submission, then will slide to the next item (form) for the next slide and the process will go on. Into this I am using the load method as I need to check every time the data. But everything is working fine with my codes only the issue is after form submit I am unable to move the owl carousel slide to next. I have used the owl carousel change events but it says `owl is not defined`.

This is what we have used for loading the carousel on modal

```
$(document).on('click','#click',function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var id = '<?php echo $asses; ?>';
$('.modal-loader').show();

$("#onboardingScreens .modal-body").load("{{ route('preview_modal',$asses) }}", function() { 
    $('.modal-loader').hide();
    $("#onboardingScreens").modal("show"); 
    var owl = $('.owl-carousel');
    owl.owlCarousel({
        loop:false,
        margin:10,
        responsiveClass:true,
        nav: false,
        dots:false,
        touchDrag:false,
        mouseDrag:false,
        items: 1,
    });
      
    
    $('.customNextBtn').click(function() {
        owl.trigger('next.owl.carousel');
    });
    $('.customPreviousBtn').click(function() {
        owl.trigger('prev.owl.carousel');
    });

});

return false;
});
```

This is what I have used for form submit

```
$(document).on('submit','.database_operation',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var url = $(this).attr('action');
  var data = $(this).serialize();
  var div_count = $('div.active > div').attr('dot-item');
  var currentIndex = $('div.active').index() + 1;
  console.log(div_count,currentIndex);
  $.ajax({
      url:$(this).attr('action'),
      method:$(this).attr('method'),
      data:new FormData(this),
      processData:false,
      dataType:'json',
      contentType:false,
      beforeSend:function(){
        
        $('.modal-loader').show();
        if(currentIndex == div_count){
            $("div.active").find(".form-check").removeClass("error-back");
            $("div.active").find(".form-check").removeClass("success-back");
        }
      },
      success:function(data){
        
        $('.modal-loader').hide();
        if(data.status == 0){
            <!-- If form submit is okay from here I want to change the slide -->
            owl.on('changed.owl.carousel', function(event) {
                
            })
        }else if(data.status == 1){

            swal({
                title: "Error",
                text: data.error,
                type: "error"
            }, function () {
                
            });

        }
        
          
      }
      

  });
  
  return false;
});
```